# what should I do with geemap library map illustration?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am using geemap on my project but the map which came up it is not like the one presented in the documentation and does not provide the icon that helps to select layers. what should I do?

```
Map = geemap.Map()
Map
```

[what it shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71NKF.png)

[What it supposed to be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAupb.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the

> folium-based Map

After adding the wanted layer and before displaying the Map object, you may try to add a layer control:

```
import geemap.eefolium as geemap

Map = geemap.Map()

Map.add_basemap('Esri National Geographic')

Map.add_layer_control()

Map
```